# Passing C# Property to a function using ref

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a C# property in "public ClassA "as follows: //assume private fields exist

```
public String Test
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    set
    {
        _test= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Test");
    }
}
```

If I update the value of Test from ClassA member functions I get notified of its property change.

But if I pass this property to a function belonging to some other class, as a parameter, and change its value from there I don't get notified.

Is it because it's getting passed by value ?
I thought I would try passing this with ref but that doesn't compile.

How do I pass this property to any function and still get notified of the change ?

Comment: but I want it to change and have its setter get called.

Comment: Is there any alternative because that would require some significant code changes for me. Is there any workaround of passing properties by reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass the property's value to another method as a parameter, then change its value, the value of the property remains unchanged.

How about passing the parent object and manipulating its properties at the receiving end? After all the setter belongs to that object, not to the value it holds.

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing will lead to incredibly smelly code. A simple way to achieve this is to call the function, and assign its return value to your property:

```
this.Test = SomeObject.CallSomeFunction();
```

this will achieve the objective of keeping your code nice and simple, and it will trigger the property change notification. You could call the target function and pass a reference of the caller to it (`SomeObject.CallSomeFunction(this);`), but in 99% of cases you shouldn't be doing this simply so the target function can manipulate the properties of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because it's getting passed by value ?

Yes

> I thought I would try passing this with ref but that doesn't compile

Because only fields and variables can be passed by reference; properties are actually more like methods (actually pairs of methods: get/set). A workaround is to do something like that:

```
string test = Test;
SomeMethod(ref test);
Test = test;
```